# Disallowing User Listing in SCIM API WSO2

Tags: wso2, scim

I'm using wso2 IS version 5.3.0. How do I block user from listing users, but allow retrieving data of a single user and creating users?
An example for list user operation mentioned above:

`curl -X GET \
   https://some.domain:9443/wso2/scim/Users \
   -H 'accept: application/json' \
   -u <user>:<password> \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'content-type: application/json' \`

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Authenticating+and+Authorizing+REST+APIs

But it can a pain and can lack granularity (Disable for everybody including Super Tenant admin or not). Usually WSO2 Professional Services recommend to use WSO2 API Manager (or any other) in front of it to manage more granular permissions.

Jeff